# Object type in <apex:inputField> for color picker

Tags: apex, visualforce, color-picker

I'm trying to develop a color picker using [JSColor](http://jscolor.com/) but I don't know how to do it with an `<apex:inputField>`.
I have the error below :

> Save error: Could not resolve the entity from value binding
>   '{!color}'. can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are
>   Visualforce field component resolvable.

Here's my code :

VF :

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="color" value="{!color}" />
```

Controller :

```
public SObject color {get; set;}
```

I can't use another object type like `String`. But it doesn't work with `SObject`.

Do I need to use a standard object like `Account` or a custom object saved in database ?
I don't want to create a custom object only for store the color. If possible I just want to store it in a controller field.

Comment: Try to use `apex:inputText` instead.

Comment: So obvious, I didn't think about that. Thanks mast0r, it works but now I have a problem with the JSColor library. I can't see the color I'm choosing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SObject is a complex type. Therefore you cannot assign a simple value like a color code (string).

In your case it makes sense to add a custom field to your sObject (e.g. Color__c). This field can be referenced by anAccount.Color__c.

**Example**

```
public Account anAccount {get; set;}
```

And

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="color" value="{!anAccount.Color__c}" />
```